# Merge unit test reports from multi projects Gradle build

Tags: testing, gradle

I have a multi module Gradle script with 3 modules: `common`, `services` and `web`.

If I run `gradle check` all the test suite is performed correctly, but I don't have a single test report instead I found a test report for each subproject. How can I merge the test results?

If useful this is the script I'm using https://github.com/CarloMicieli/trenako/blob/master/build.gradle

Thanks
Carlo

Comment: Don't know if this will work but you can try settings the `reportsDir` property to the same directory for all subprojects (see http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N11E97)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gradle source contains a Task class used to accomplish this, which unfortunately isn't available in the public API. Basically all it does is copy all of the test reports from various projects into one directory and then run the standard test report task to get an aggregate. Check out the source code at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/build/TestReportAggregator.groovy

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to create a task following your advice.

Comment: The page doesn't exist any more or is now private